# "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale" in default data set example mtcars and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scatter-plot, scatter

I am trying to replicate [the example here (sthda.com)](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-scatter-plots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization#change-the-point-colorshapesize-manually) using the following code:

```
# Change point shapes and colors manually
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl, shape=cyl)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(3, 16, 17))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00', '#56B4E9'))+
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

The example on that web page says that code should produce the following result:

[image: plot]

But when I run it in R, I get the following error:

> "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"

Does anyone know what could be wrong with this code? Or why I am getting a different result than the example?

If someone could run the sample code and tell me if they get the same error I would be very grateful.

Comment: you missed the line `mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)` in the prepare data section

Comment: or just ``factor(mtcars$cyl)`` if you know ``cyl`` is not a factor.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yeah, I was able to fix it by converting the color and shape aesthetics to factors:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=as.factor(cyl), shape=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(3, 16, 17))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00', '#56B4E9'))+
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

Comment: Please also mention what you changed. Otherwise everyone would need to spend time on going through both codes and trying to find differences. You added `as.factor` to `color` and `shape`.

Answer (score 18):

as.factor makes it work

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=as.factor(cyl), shape=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(3, 16, 17))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00', '#56B4E9'))+
  theme(legend.position="top")
```