# change ggplot legend to discrete instead of continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I fix the legend so it isn't on a continuous scale? I would like it to say the black line corresponds to fitted values and the blue line to predicted values.

[image]

code:

```
df_pred <- data.frame(
        year = c("2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022","2023"),
        values = c(0.8888866, 0.8716710, 0.8447683, 0.8274719, 0.8321376, 0.8361800, 0.8319212, 0.8325700, 0.8551733, 0.8832598, 0.9072822, 0.9267712, 0.9424237),
        upper = c(rep(NA,10),0.9827305, 0.9919751, 0.9964064),
        lower = c(rep(NA,10),0.6272399, 0.5644133, 0.4914222),
        group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2))

ggplot(df_pred,aes(x=year, y=values, group=1, colour = group))+
  geom_line()+geom_point()+
  geom_ribbon(data=df_pred,aes(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13) ,ymin = lower, ymax = upper), inherit.aes = FALSE,fill = "lightblue", alpha=0.3)+ labs(y="Probability of sub-specialism", x = "Year")+ theme(axis.title.x = element_text( size = 14),axis.title.y = element_text(size =14)) +theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())#+ scale_color_manual(values=c("black","blue"))
```

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/a/43359106/8386140 instructive

Comment: @duckmayr Thanks, setting the group to a factor did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could set the column group as a factor,

```
df_pred$group <- as.factor(df_pred$group)
```

and change the group names (1 = fitted and 2 = predicted),

```
df_pred$group <- ifelse(df_pred$group == 1, 'fitted', 'predicted')
```

and run your code again.

[image]